# Splash screen background image doesn't work

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I'm using flutter_native_splash package for setting my own custom splash screen.
I followed the official [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) while creating the splash screen. In my flutter_native_splash.yaml file I have the following configuration:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/splash/splash_image.png
  background_image: "assets/splash/background.png"
  android_12: 
    image: assets/splash/splash_image.png
    background_image: "assets/splash/background.png"
```

When I run this, the splash image works correctly. However, the background image isn't set for the splash, it shows the regular white screen.
I would like to know if something is wrong with my configuration. If not, how can I create a splash screen with background image, maybe other way.

Comment: Have you tried running in different versions of Android?